# How to enable circular bezier curve control point?

Tags: bezier-curves

[image: Screenshot]

Anyone know how I can enable this circular yellow control point on bezier curve objects?

Comment: Where did you find the image?

Comment: Hello :). That's just the Tilt or Radius tool control area.